# Facing DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT5M while unloading 800 million of cassandra data using dsbulk tool

Tags: cassandra, dsbulk

I am trying to export 800 million of data from my single node cassandra 2.1.2 in csv file using below command:

> ./dsbulk unload --connector.name csv --connector.hosts 127.0.0.1
> --connector.port 9042 --schema.keyspace spimpetus --schema.table vidtonid --output-format csv -url /home/ctadmin/vidtonid --consistency
> LOCAL_ONE --threads 1 --max-retries 3 --operation-on-error LOG
> --enable-checkpoint true --maxConcurrentQueries 1

But getting error as given below:

```
Statement: RangeReadBoundStatement@5a735960 [2 values, idempotence: <UNSET>, CL: <UNSET>, serial CL: <UNSET>, timestamp: <UNSET>, timeout: <UNSET>]
SELECT vid, ntwk, lastntlasttime, lst FROM spimpetus.vidtonid WHERE token(vid) > :start AND token(vid) <= :end
start: -191712720052656411
end: -168481090525786222
com.datastax.oss.dsbulk.executor.api.exception.BulkExecutionException: Statement execution failed: SELECT vid, ntwk, lastntlasttime, lst FROM spimpetus.vidtonid WHERE token(vid) > :start AND token(vid) <= :end (Query timed out after PT5M)
        at com.datastax.oss.dsbulk.executor.api.subscription.ResultSubscription.toErrorPage(ResultSubscription.java:541)
        at com.datastax.oss.dsbulk.executor.api.subscription.ResultSubscription.lambda$fetchNextPage$1(ResultSubscription.java:379)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.setFinalError(CqlRequestHandler.java:450) [4 skipped]
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.lambda$scheduleTimeout$1(CqlRequestHandler.java:207)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [6 skipped]
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT5M
        ... 8 common frames omitted
```

The same command I tested for exporting 1.25 million of data and it worked fine.